# download file from Internet to server using SSH

Tags: ssh, file-copy, download

Recently because of some problem, I lost all my server files and requested the hosting team to provide me my files from a backup. They will provide me a link from which I have to download a compressed file and upload it again on server.

Is there any way to download that file directly onto the server? I have full access on the server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use the `wget` utility.

It has a really simple syntax, and all what do you need is to:

`wget http://link.to.file` and it will be stored in the same directory where do you run `wget`. If you'd like to store a downloaded file somewhere else, you may use `-P` option, e.g.

`wget -P /path/to/store http://link.to.file`

Comment: can i download more than 20GB file size using wget?

Comment: Of course, you can. Wget itself doesn't have any limitations for filesize, so the filesize-related  limits may be occurred only by source and/or destination gate.

Comment: wget is the cure!

Comment: @ihor_dvoretskyi Suppose I want to check what all files are present in `http://link`. Is there any way that I can search for the files present in the given link. If I do the above procedure then in downloads the index.html file from the link provided, but I wanted to know the list of all the files that are present on the server/link.

Comment: awesome! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Of course, use `scp`. It behaves roughly like `cp`. Sample:

```
scp username@hostname:/remote/path/to/file local_path
```

You can recursively copy directories with `-r`

That's if you really need to download it via `ssh`. If they provide you just with an url (your question wasn't clear), then `wget` or `curl` will do the job, no need for `ssh`.

Comment: what to provide in username and hostname??

Comment: Quote from OP: *they will provide me link from where i have to download* What is not clear about that? :-)

Comment: file to download from their server url of that file, no login required.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ssh` to login to your server, then use for example `wget` to download the file

```
wget https://provided_link
```